# How to get previous row value in present row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way we can get previous row data in present row in SQL Server

For eg I have a table as

```
id  |  name
1   |  abc
2   |  def
3   |  xyz
```

I need to query data in the following manner .. so as to concatenate previous row with present one

This way

```
id  |  name
1   |  abc
2   |  abcdef
3   |  abcdefxyz
```

I tries with lag() but, couldn't figure out what am I doing wrong. I am very new in SQL Server.. I am not aware of other functions that could help

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look like you want `LAG` (at least not on it's own). `LAG` returns value of the prior row, *not* the prior row**s**. It returns a *scalar* value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [String_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function like below

```
create table t (id  int,  name nvarchar(max));
insert into t values (1 , 'abc'),(2, 'def'),(3,'xyz');

select t1.id,string_agg(t2.name,'') from t t1 left join t t2 
on t1.id>=t2.id
group by t1.id
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b253cae92f23dd6711eee3266718ddb6)